ERROR: superblock checksum mismatch. how to solve this error?
My laptop suddenly got this error. How can I solve it?
enter image description here
view of fdisk:
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 894.25 GiB, 960197124096 bytes, 1875385008 sectors
Disk model: Force MP510                             
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D3EEB967-8E74-C64B-A11A-97441E410542

Device              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1       4096     618495     614400   300M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2     618496 1856924965 1856306470 885.2G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 1856924966 1875379904   18454939   8.8G Linux swap


Disk /dev/sda: 28.91 GiB, 31037849600 bytes, 60620800 sectors
Disk model: USB Flash Drive 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0572d551

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       64 10321919 10321856  4.9G  0 Empty
/dev/sda2        2508     4299     1792  896K ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)


Disk /dev/loop0: 4.78 GiB, 5132718080 bytes, 10024840 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

when i check btrfs i got this:
$sudo btrfs check /dev/nvme0n1p2

Opening filesystem to check...
Checking filesystem on /dev/nvme0n1p2
UUID: 685fabb9-64b3-430c-9787-18f661d6ff05
[1/7] checking root items
[2/7] checking extents
[3/7] checking free space tree
[4/7] checking fs roots
[5/7] checking only csums items (without verifying data)
[6/7] checking root refs
[7/7] checking quota groups skipped (not enabled on this FS)
found 147456 bytes used, no error found
total csum bytes: 0
total tree bytes: 147456
total fs tree bytes: 32768
total extent tree bytes: 16384
btree space waste bytes: 140595
file data blocks allocated: 0
 referenced 0

and:
$sudo fsck -yf /dev/nvme0n1p2 
fsck from util-linux 2.38.1

My laptop operating system is Debian 12. I think my laptop has a hardware problem. Because after moving, this problem was created.
